# C++ - Output ASCII to cmd.exe?

Tags: c++, windows, batch-file, cmd, piping

So, I believe I have to pipe the I/O from my application to cmd.exe. I'm trying to make a sort of "command" for cmd, where it can be called from cmd directly or from via a batch file. I do not want a window, which is why I'm using `WinMain` as the entry point, no window-creation function is in my application, so no window will be created, I assume.

If I'm required to pipe I/O from my application to a currently open cmd window, doesn't that involve grabbing cmd's output handle, passing a string of text (ASCII) to its output (maybe the `echo` command?)

Am I on the right track, or not? I'm currently searching Google and SOF for methods on piping I/O to other running console programs, and will be searching until then.

Also, is there any way to grab variables stored inside cmd itself? In batch, you can call a variable via `%variable%` or, if `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` is switched on, you can use `!variable!`. If so, how?

Comment: This has symptoms of an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: Jerry, I'm attempting to output ASCII text to cmd, after grabbing a parameter specified in command-line arguments in the actual C++ application when called from cmd or a batch file. For example, I need to call `application.exe -argument_here` from a batch file. When the application is opened, I need to print some text to the cmd console window, not my application's window (since I call to function to create any window in my code). Does that help any? I believe that makes it even a bit more unclear. Sorry about the XY question.

Comment: Don't use a Windows framework (`WinMain`) but simply `main`? Then you would be creating a simple command-line utility, which I believe is your intention.

Comment: @Mike - You are aware that Windows has support for traditional command line programs, right?  You write your code with main() as the entry point of the code and flag the project settings in Visual Studio such that your program compiles as a CONSOLE application.  Then you can use the normal | < and > chars in commands to pipe or redirect input/output.

Comment: @selbie, Yes, I know. One of the answers on another question here on SOF suggested that I use `WinMain` as my entry point since I don't want any kind of application window to pop up.

Answer (score 0):

No, you are off the mark. The answer is much simpler :-)

Simply write to stdout. Write any error messages to stderr, and for input, read from stdin. Those streams are setup to write to the console (unless the console has had its input/output redirected). Your program can then be used as a command useful for batch scripting. It will properly honor any redirection or pipe that is instantiated from the command line or batch script, with no further work required on your part.

Comment: And `stdout` is used for printing text to cmd's console window? I'll try it out and get back to you later. How would I go about utilizing `stdout` to print to cmd's text console?